# Key.create vs. ofy().load()

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to get the key to an entity (I don't need the actual entity. I need the key just to get a child entity).

So I know there are two ways of doing it:

```
// 1.
Key<Thing> tKey = com.googlecode.objectify.Key.create(Thing.class, id);

// 2.
Key<Thing> tKey = ofy().load().type(Thing.class).id(id);
```

What's the difference between them? what's faster? Which one should I use?

Would the answer change if I had to do this as well:

```
Thing t = tKey.get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Key.create(Thing, id)`.

`ofy().load().type(Thing.class).id(id)` returns a `Ref<Thing>`, not a `Key<Thing>`. It actually loads the thing out of the datastore, which is not what you want.